# I need to pass two elements to an onclick event handling function JavaScript and not just their id's

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Suppose I have two elements in my code and I want to pass their respective id's to an event handling function. (In my example below, I have a div and a button)

```
<div id="div1">
  <input type="button" id="button1" onclick="doSomething(this, [here comes id of div])" />
</div>
```

For the button, instead of writing the id which is "button1", I simply passed the element itself using the `this` keyword. Now my question is, is there a way where I can pass the div element itself in the function and not just its id just like what I did with the button element?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`parentNode` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode);

```
this.parentNode
```

As this returns a `DOMElement` (similar to `this`), you can access the ID the same via;

```
this.parentNode.id
```

... should you want to.

Comment: What if I want to access the parent of my parent? In short, the grandparent node?

Comment: @RenzoMontejo: use `parentNode` again; `this.parentNode.parentNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Just get it from the parent in the callback:

```
function clickHandler(e){
    console.log(e.target.parentNode.id);
}
```

Comment: You may want to point out that solution requires jQuery which this post is not tagged with.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in this answer - event handlers can be attached via el.addEventListener( ... ) [or el.attachEvent( ... ) in ie]

Comment: I had it in there before; my b

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to pass it in the first place? Access the div via [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode).

```
onclick="doSomething(this);"
```

and

```
function doSomething(btn) {
   var div = btn.parentNode;
}
```